# Parsing delimiter-separated values in F#

Tags: .net, parsing, f#, text-parsing

I am parsing string records in this form:

```
description: double/double/double
```

for ex.:

```
item description: 0.4/8/-24.66
```

Each record should result in an object:

```
new MyObj("first item", 0.4, 2.4, -24.66)
```

I could easily do this with a regular expression and a procedural approach, but the resulting code is error-prone and rather ugly (at least from a functional point of view).

How can this be accomplished in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can just create a simple parser function `string->MyObj` like this:

```
type MyObj(descr:string, a:float, b:float, c:float) =
    override this.ToString() =
        System.String.Format("{0}: {1}; {2}; {3}", descr,a,b,c)

let myobjfromstr (str:string) = 
    let flds = str.Split([|':';'/'|])
    let ip s = System.Double.Parse(s)    
    new MyObj(flds.[0], ip flds.[1], ip flds.[2], ip flds.[3])

myobjfromstr "item description: 0.4/8/-24.66" |> printfn "%A"
```

(*update:* I guessed that records were separated by a new-line or something like that and were split into a list. On the second thought, there's nothing like that in your question...)

Comment: Simple but effective, I like it! Records are separated by newlines, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori, it's also worth noting that it's possible to create a function like `string->seq<MyObj>` which is, imho, very F#-esque. Also, Don Syme wrote in his book that you shouldn't be afraid of mutable fields and procedural approaches as long as it gives you necessary performance boost and is well-hidden inside a function or type... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Well, FParsec is nice:

```
#r "FParsecCS.dll"
#r "FParsec.dll"

open FParsec

let parser : Parser<_,unit> =
    sepBy pfloat (pchar '/')
```

And then `run parser "0.4/8/-24.66"` returns `val it : ParserResult<float list,unit> = Success: [0.4; 8.0; -24.66]`.

Comment: Looks good, except I also need the first part of the record (the string before the colon). I also would be interested in a solution that does not make use of external libs.

Comment: For the first part you could do ``many1Chars (notAnyOf [':']) .>> skipChar ':'``. For not using external libs, don't use FParsec :)